# creating mock phpunit discrepency in mocked namespace and the original one

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, php-7.2

I have function like this:

```
class Bar{
    public function a():Foo{
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

now I am trying to create a mock for the class Bar with php unit test

```
    $mockedBar = $this->getMockBuilder(Bar::class)
     ->getMock()
     ->method('a')
     ->willReturn(new FakeFoo());
```

but when I am calling method `a` I am getting an error that method `a` return type must be instance of Foo not Mocked_blahblah.

unfortunately class Bar don't use any interface and the system is very big and I can't create an interface cause it make huge refactor in my codes;
is there any way to disable return type of function `a` in mocked object?
I am useing php7.2 and phpunit 6.0.13.
Here is a real scenario:

```
class A
{
    public function b():B
    {
        echo "i am from class A function b";
    }
}
class B
{

}

class FakeB
{
}
class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSayHi(){
        $mockedA = $this->getMockBuilder(A::class)
            ->getMock();
        $mockedA->method('b')->willReturn(new FakeB());
        $mockedA->b();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable return types. Perhaps you could try to do it with some kind of a hackish error handler, but it's a crazy thing to do.

Good news is that you're not trying to do anything unusual and your tests can be fixed.

Firstly, you need to assign the result of `getMock` to a variable. Next, you can define your test double:

```php
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIt()
    {
        $mockedBar = $this->getMockBuilder(Bar::class)->getMock();
        $mockedBar
             ->method('a')
             ->willReturn(new FakeFoo());

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Foo::class, $mockedBar->a());
    }
}
```

This will only work if `FakeFoo` is of type of `Foo`, for example extends it:

```php
class FakeFoo extends Foo
{
    // override any Foo methods you'd like to fake
}
```

You don't need to create a Fake yourself, you can use PHPUnit to create a dummy:

```php
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testIt()
    {
        $mockedBar = $this->createMock(Bar::class);
        $mockedBar
             ->method('a')
             ->willReturn($this->createMock(Foo::class));

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Foo::class, $mockedBar->a());
    }
}
```

To fix your second example:

```php
class A
{
    public function b():B
    {
        echo "i am from class A function b";
    }
}

class B
{
}

class FakeB extends B
{
}

class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSayHi(){
        $mockedA = $this->getMockBuilder(A::class)->getMock();
        $mockedA->method('b')->willReturn(new FakeB());
        $mockedA->b();
    }
}
```

Or, instead of using a fake let phpunit handle it:

```
class ATest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSayHi(){
        $mockedA = $this->getMockBuilder(A::class)->getMock();
        $dummyB = $this->createMock(B::class);

        $mockedA->method('b')->willReturn($dummyB);
        $mockedA->b();
    }
}
```